# Not able to receive data in activity from foreground service in app android

Tags: java, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-broadcast

I am making an app that reads data being sent via Bluetooth in one activity which then is redirected to a foreground service which sends an intent to another activity where the data will be processed. I know I am missing something in the code for the broadcast receiver on the activity code.

If anyone can give me advice or help me with the data being able to be processed. There are no crashes so far. I am new in coding in android studio and any help would be great!

*** This is the code for the Foreground Service  ***

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {

public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    Log.i("Tag", input);
    sendData(input);
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
        return null;
}

private void sendData(String input){
    Log.i("Tag", "inside sendData");
   
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.example.Pillwoah.sendbroadcast");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    intent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Foreground Service Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}

}
```

*** This is the code for the activity  ***

```
public class MainActivity5 extends AppCompatActivity {

protected static final String TAG = "TAG";

TextView dataText;

BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

    Log.i(TAG, "data sending");
    configureReceiver();
}

class DataBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = "Broadcast intent detected " + intent.getAction();
        Log.i(TAG, message);
    }
}

private void configureReceiver(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.example.Pillwoah.sendbroadcast");
    receiver = new DataBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

}
```

Comment: When the foreground `Service` is started, it sends a broadcast `Intent`.  This `Intent` should be caught by `DataBroadcastReceiver` in `MainActivity5`, assuming that `MainActivity5` is running at the time. It is difficult from the code snippets you have provided to understand your architecture. What starts the foreground `Service`?

Comment: I have an intent in MainActivity4 in onCharacteristicChanged function that takes the incoming data to the foreground service

Comment: Is `MainActivty5` running? How does this get launched?